# Can not connect nodes to docker swarm master (using zookeeper)

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

I am building my docker swarm cluster in a sandbox.
I have 1 zookeeper on a machine for discovery, 1 swarm master and 2 swarm nodes.
I try to connect them but when I try to run my docker run commands on the swarm master, it does not distribute the work to the nodes.
Also when I do `docker info` on the swarm master I can see that the nodes are not connected.
I do not know what I am doing wrong.
Here are the step to reproduce my problem:

I have an empty `pwd`/data folder and a `pwd`/config folder with my zoo.cfg:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
```

-

```
#---- CREATE ZOO ---

docker-machine create --driver virtualbox zoo1
docker-machine start zoo1
eval $(docker-machine env zoo1)

docker pull jplock/zookeeper

docker run -p 2181:2181 -v `pwd`/conf:/opt/zookeeper/conf -v `pwd`/data:/tmp/zookeeper jplock/zookeeper

docker-machine ip zoo1 #############192.168.99.100
```

-

```
#--- CREATE CLUSTER ---

docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm --swarm-master machine-smaster
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm machine-s01
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm machine-s02
```

-

```
eval "$(docker-machine env machine-smaster)"
docker run -p 2375:2375 -d -t swarm manage -H 0.0.0.0:2375 --advertise $(docker-machine ip machine-smaster):2375 zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm
docker run swarm list zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm

sleep 10

eval "$(docker-machine env machine-s01)"
docker run -d swarm join --advertise $(docker-machine ip machine-s01):2375 zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm
docker run swarm list zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm

eval "$(docker-machine env machine-s02)"
docker run -d swarm join --advertise $(docker-machine ip machine-s02):2375 zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm
docker run swarm list zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm
```

If I run some containers:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env machine-smaster)"
docker run hello-world
```

The work is not dispatched to nodes (it is run by the master).
If I run docker info:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env machine-smaster)"
docker info
```

I do not see the swarm nodes.

Comment: I think you're connecting with the *docker* API, not the *swarm* API for master; try `eval "$(docker-machine env --swarm machine-smaster)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you verify that the addresses you're advertising are actually reachable from the manager instance?  i.e., does `docker -H $(docker-machine ip machine-s01):2375 info` return a valid result?

(Note that this subshell won't work inside the manager VM, just on your original client.)

Maybe your problem is that the started Docker Machine instances are listening on `:2376` *with* TLS, but your started Swarm containers are trying to advertise and connect to `:2375` *without* any TLS settings specified?

What do the `docker logs` for the Swarm containers say?

Comment: `docker -H $(docker-machine ip machine-s01):2375 info` from the machine-smaster gives me: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host? `docker logs`: time="2016-04-12T20:57:50Z" level=fatal msg="discovery required to manage a cluster. See 'swarm manage --help'." I removed all the tls options on swarm manage and tried `docker logs` `INFO[0000] Initializing discovery without TLS INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP addr=0.0.0.0:2375 proto=tcp` but the first command is still invalid

Comment: I have set up a githup repo to reproduce my problem easily: https://github.com/casertap/playing-with-docker-swarm

Comment: @pierolele, that's exactly my point.  You can't connect to the Docker host/port that you're advertising the Swarm containers on, so of course it will fail.  You need to advertise <ip>:2376 and also ensure that the certificates are bind-mounted into the manager container properly using `-v`.

Comment: I solved it like such: `docker run -p 3376:3376 -d -t -v /var/lib/boot2docker:/certs:ro swarm manage --tlsverify --tlscacert=/certs/ca.pem --tlscert=/certs/server.pem --tlskey=/certs/server-key.pem -H 0.0.0.0:3376 zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm` I changed for the port 3376 for -H and leave all the docker-machine like such: `docker run -d swarm join --advertise $(docker-machine ip machine-s01):2376 zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm` I do not understand why 2376 and not 3376?

Comment: I think I understand. When a container join it advertise itself has being on <node_ip>:<any_port_you_want>. The discovery mechanism takes this info and gives it to the swarm master. Now the swarm master knows it has one more swarm node. The node never talks to the swarm master directly. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right: The nodes use the KV store for discovery.  Master talks to nodes to schedule containers but they don't talk back.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're connecting to the "Swarm master" machine through the *Docker* API, not the *Swarm* API. Because of this, Docker will always deploy containers on the host you're connected to, and does not take advantage of Swarm scheduling the containers on the right host.

To connect to the *Swarm* API, add the `--swarm` option when running `docker-machine env`, so in your case:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env --swarm machine-smaster)"
```

Comment: Here is what I get when running with --swarm:
    `$ eval "$(docker-machine env --swarm machine-smaster)"`
    Error checking TLS connection: Connection to Swarm cannot be checked but the certs are valid. Maybe swarm is not started
    `$ eval "$(docker-machine env machine-smaster)"`
    `$ docker ps`

f5bb895cdad9        swarm               "/swarm manage -H 0.0"   51 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds       0.0.0.0:2375->2375/tcp   tiny_kowalevski

Comment: I think the swarm master is started without TLS, and docker-machine tries to communicate with TLS. Also see https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/

Comment: So instead of `docker run -p 2375:2375 -d -t swarm manage -H 0.0.0.0:2375 --advertise $(docker-machine ip machine-smaster):2375 zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm` I added all the TLS related options:
`docker run -p 2375:2375 -d -t -v /var/lib/boot2docker:/certs:ro swarm manage --tlsverify --tlscacert=/certs/ca.pem --tlscert=/certs/server.pem --tlskey=/certs/server-key.pem -H 0.0.0.0:2375 --advertise $(docker-machine ip machine-smaster):2375 zk://192.168.99.101:2181/swarm` I get the same TLS error as before

Comment: Now the command: `docker run swarm list zk://192.168.99.100:2181/swarm` is still giving me the output: `time="2016-04-12T00:37:26Z" level=info msg="Initializing discovery without TLS"
2016/04/12 00:37:26 Connected to 192.168.99.100:2181`
but I do not think this is the problem.